# Error while sending BigBlueButton API request - 'cannot handle recieved message' in red5 log (while sending create meeting request)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, ruby-on-rails-4, bigbluebutton

I have installed BBB in my server and was using it without any problem. But for past 20 days am facing a problem i couldnt use BBB, when i send a api request to create a meeting the response is:

```
Invalid response body. Is the API URL correct? "http://180.151.96.73/bigbluebutton/api", version 0.81
```

When i check the logs in my BBB server it gives me the following error:

```
ubuntu-dos@ubuntudos:~$ sudo bbb-conf --debug
   -- ERRORS found in /usr/share/red5/log/* -- 
/usr/share/red5/log/bigbluebutton.log:2014-03-15 23:27:21,781 [pool-9-thread-1] ERROR   o.b.c.s.p.ConversionUpdatesMessageListener - Cannot handle recieved message.
```

When i give the following url(Server where i hosted BBB),

```
http://myip/bigbluebutton/api
```

am getting the following response which gives success response,

```
<response>
<returncode>SUCCESS</returncode>
<version>0.81</version>
</response>
```

but when i send create meeting or any other request through my app it gives me the above error, i dont know how to solve this issue. Could any one please help me in this

My app is created using,

```
Rails - 3.2.9
Ruby - ruby 1.9.3p484
am using gem 'bigbluebutton-api-ruby' to work with BBB api.
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have been the case that bigbluebutton-api-ruby did not support BigBlueButton 0.81 at the time. Since version 1.3.0 it supports BigBlueButton 0.81. Try to use this new version and check if it solves the problem.

Also, you can create your `BigBlueButtonApi` object setting the `debug` flag to `true` (https://github.com/mconf/bigbluebutton-api-ruby/blob/v1.3.0/lib/bigbluebutton_api.rb#L70) and check your output (it outputs with `puts`) to see if the URLs being called by the gem are correct.